# How to derive the week start for a given (iso) weeknumber / year in python

Tags: python, datetime, calendar

I know I can use `datetime.isocalendar()` for getting the weeknumber given a certain date. How can I do the inverse, given a weeknumber and year retrieve the first day of that week.

Comment: The question sounds a lot like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396913/in-python-how-do-i-find-the-date-of-the-first-monday-of-a-given-week).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're limited to stdlib you could do the following:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2011, 4, 0', '%Y, %U, %w')
datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 23, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Note: this will not use ISO week number, so the start of the year is calculated differently ;)

Comment: Agree with @iElectric. This is incorrect. You're using different calendars, so values are not preserved. Try this, and you'll see the date after the conversion changes:  
  
`>>> iso_tuple = datetime.date(2003, 12, 29).isocalendar()  
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('%d, %d, %d' % iso_tuple, '%Y, %U, %w')  
datetime.datetime(2004, 1, 5, 0, 0)  `

Comment: Sorry for the mangled code in the comment. It doesn't accept line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find a standard library, so had to roll my own. Main difficulty is finding the first day of the ISO year (which could be in the previous year). You'll need to add some input checks etc...

```
import datetime
def isoWeekToGregorian(isoYear, isoWeek, isoDayOfWeek):
    #we have to find the date of the iso year
    t0 = datetime.datetime(isoYear,1,1,0,0,0)
    t0iso = t0.isocalendar()
    if (t0iso[1] != 1):
        t0prime = t0 + datetime.timedelta(7-t0iso[2])
    else:
        t0prime = t0 - datetime.timedelta(t0iso[2])
    #we can add our weeks and days...
    return t0prime + datetime.timedelta(7*(isoWeek-1) + isoDayOfWeek)
```

We can create a simple test:

```
#TEST: we know 2004 has 53 weeks...
t0 = datetime.datetime(2004,12,26,0,0,0)
t1 = datetime.datetime(2005,1,10,0,0,0)
ndays = (t1-t0).days + 1
for i in range(ndays):
    d0 = t0 + datetime.timedelta(i)
    d0iso = d0.isocalendar()
    if (d0 != isoWeekToGregorian(d0iso[0],d0iso[1],d0iso[2])):
        print "failed: %s" % d0
    else:
        print d0, d0iso
```

Which correctly prints:

```
2004-12-26 00:00:00 (2004, 52, 7)
2004-12-27 00:00:00 (2004, 53, 1)
2004-12-28 00:00:00 (2004, 53, 2)
2004-12-29 00:00:00 (2004, 53, 3)
2004-12-30 00:00:00 (2004, 53, 4)
2004-12-31 00:00:00 (2004, 53, 5)
2005-01-01 00:00:00 (2004, 53, 6)
2005-01-02 00:00:00 (2004, 53, 7)
2005-01-03 00:00:00 (2005, 1, 1)
2005-01-04 00:00:00 (2005, 1, 2)
2005-01-05 00:00:00 (2005, 1, 3)
2005-01-06 00:00:00 (2005, 1, 4)
2005-01-07 00:00:00 (2005, 1, 5)
2005-01-08 00:00:00 (2005, 1, 6)
2005-01-09 00:00:00 (2005, 1, 7)
2005-01-10 00:00:00 (2005, 2, 1)
```