# get first day of this week in python

Tags: python-2.7

IS there any way I can find the first day of the current week in python.
Similarly for current month and 3 months before. This is for a filter based in periods.

I am very new to python. I am extremely sorry, if this is a stupid Question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No need of sorry.  I am not sure about python.  But I think, It can be easily done using javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The question has been asked many times before. Please have a look at [In Python, how do I find the date of the first Monday of a given week?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396913/in-python-how-do-i-find-the-date-of-the-first-monday-of-a-given-week)
That should help you getting on the right track

Comment: Thanks Yorick..!! Let me try this.