# How to get a list of dates from a week number in python

Tags: python, django

So I know the week number of a date using `x = mydate.strftime("%U")` now I need to find all the dates that fall in that week. Ultimately I need to get a query set from django on date object that returns all records that are in a given week based only on knowing the week number. Something like:

```
y = Stuff.objects.filter=(date__range=[#anydate that is in the week number of x])
```

Comment: I think it would be easier to use dayofweek as an offset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Arrow for that:

```
import arrow

def get_week(dt):
    mydate = arrow.get(dt)
    start = mydate.floor('week')
    end = mydate.ceil('week')
    return arrow.Arrow.range('day', start, end)
```

Output:

```
In [369]: list(get_week(datetime.datetime.utcnow()))
Out[369]: 
[<Arrow [2015-04-20T00:00:00+00:00]>,
 <Arrow [2015-04-21T00:00:00+00:00]>,
 <Arrow [2015-04-22T00:00:00+00:00]>,
 <Arrow [2015-04-23T00:00:00+00:00]>,
 <Arrow [2015-04-24T00:00:00+00:00]>,
 <Arrow [2015-04-25T00:00:00+00:00]>,
 <Arrow [2015-04-26T00:00:00+00:00]>]
```

Answer (score 4):

Adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/396926/170005), you could do this with Python's inbuilt modules - time, datetime.

Here's the code:

```
import time
import datetime

WEEK  = 21
startdate = time.asctime(time.strptime('2008 %d 1' % WEEK, '%Y %W %w'))
startdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(startdate, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
dates = [startdate]
for i in range(1, 7):
    dates.append(startdate + datetime.timedelta(days=i))

print dates

## -- End pasted text --
[datetime.datetime(2008, 5, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2008, 5, 27, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2008, 5, 28, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2008, 5, 29, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2008, 5, 30, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2008, 5, 31, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2008, 6, 1, 0, 0)]
```