# how to get all dates of week based on week number in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I want all the dates of the present week based on weeknumber.

I can get week number like

```
import datetime
weeknum=datetime.datetime.now().isocalendar()[1]
```

result is 20.

wanted all dates of week 20.
the final output should be

```
dates=['2019-05-12','2019-05-13','2019-05-14','2019-05-15','2019-05-16','2019-05-17','2019-05-18']
```

please help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it with `time` and `datetime` as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29855081/how-to-get-a-list-of-dates-from-a-week-number-in-python) answer suggest but change it to your requirements:

```
WEEK  = 20 - 2 # as it starts with 0 and you want week to start from sunday
startdate = time.asctime(time.strptime('2019 %d 0' % WEEK, '%Y %W %w')) 
startdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(startdate, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y') 
dates = [startdate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')] 
for i in range(1, 7): 
    day = startdate + datetime.timedelta(days=i)
    dates.append(day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Output as following:

```
dates = ['2019-05-12',
         '2019-05-13',
         '2019-05-14',
         '2019-05-15',
         '2019-05-16',
         '2019-05-17',
         '2019-05-18']
```

Comment: Why the need to convert to and from strings? Just keep it in datetime/date object

Comment: @Will because it was one of requirements to return a list of strings.

Comment: OK. Question and example was a bit ambiguous. OP wanted to supply week number but also uses datetime.now() in example.

Comment: Would it be possible to assign the the year value to a variable?

Answer (score 6):

Use timedelta and a list comprehension.

```
import datetime
theday = datetime.date.today()
weekday = theday.isoweekday()
# The start of the week
start = theday - datetime.timedelta(days=weekday)
# build a simple range
dates = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=d) for d in range(7)]
```

---

To get output in strings

```
dates = [str(d) for d in dates]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import datetime

# Starts with knowing the day of the week
week_day=datetime.datetime.now().isocalendar()[2]

# Calculates Starting date (Sunday) for this case by subtracting current date with time delta of the day of the week
start_date=datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=week_day)

# Prints the list of dates in a current week
dates=[str((start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=i)).date()) for i in range(7)]
dates
```

The Output is:

```
>>> dates
['2019-05-12', '2019-05-13', '2019-05-14', '2019-05-15', '2019-05-16', '2019-05-17', '2019-05-18']
```

Hope this can help you. Have a nice day. :D

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can use `python` `fromisocalendar()` function

```
year = 2023
week = 12

startdate = datetime.date.fromisocalendar(year, week, 1)

dates = []
for i in range(7):
   day = startdate + datetime.timedelta(days=i)
   dates.append(day)
```

the output will be:

```
[
  "2023-03-20",
  "2023-03-21",
  "2023-03-22",
  "2023-03-23",
  "2023-03-24",
  "2023-03-25",
  "2023-03-26"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at both of the below questions. The first should help you to calculate the starting date given a week number - don't forget to specify your year.

[Get date from week number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087314/get-date-from-week-number)

I would then use the below answer and instead of using a start/end date, use your start date from above and add 1 day; 6 times and store each new date in an array.

[Python: give start and end of week data from a given date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216334/python-give-start-and-end-of-week-data-from-a-given-date)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is this -

```
weekdates = []
week_number = datetime.datetime.now().isocalendar()[1]
for day in range(7):
    week_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("2019-W{}".format(week_number)+ '-{}'.format(day), "%Y-W%W-%w")
    weekdates.append(week_date)
```

What this does is, this leverages the date format conversion to construct a date according to the day in the week.

Hope this helps.

Comment: its showing error as below

ValueError: time data '2019-W20-7' does not match format '%Y-W%W-%w'

Comment: Just a second, let me see

Answer (score 0):

For those who need the output dates to start from a monday can tweak it like this:

```
import time
import datetime

WEEK  = 20 - 1 # as it starts with 0 and you want week to start from sunday
startdate = time.asctime(time.strptime('2019 %d 1' % WEEK, '%Y %W %w')) 
startdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(startdate, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y') 
dates = [startdate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')] 
for i in range(1, 7): 
    day = startdate + datetime.timedelta(days=i)
    dates.append(day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
print(dates)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the previous 14 days, the current day, and the following 14 days as candidates. Finally, check for which date week number is similar to the current week number:

```
import datetime

def week_to_dates():
    date = datetime.date.today()
    week = date.strftime("%V")

    candidates = [date - datetime.timedelta(days=k) for k in range(14, 0, -1)] + \
                 [date] + \
                 [date + datetime.timedelta(days=k) for k in range(1, 15)]
    return [candidate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for candidate in candidates if candidate.strftime("%V") == week]
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.