# Get all dates in a given week based on week and year?

Tags: python

Is there a way to extract all dates in a week given year and week, with the first date starting on a monday? E.g. if I provide the year "2020" and week "2", I should get

`['2020-01-06', '2020-01-07', '2020-01-08', '2020-01-09', '2020-01-10', '2020-01-11', '2020-01-12']`

Comment: Can you explain *how* you arrived at this result, and what is preventing you from translating it into Python?

Comment: this is a dublicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56163008/how-to-get-all-dates-of-week-based-on-week-number-in-python/56164212 please search before creating questions :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get all dates of week based on week number in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56163008/how-to-get-all-dates-of-week-based-on-week-number-in-python)

Comment: All those answer base it on sundays as the start of the week - not monday

Comment: @erikvm There isn't going to be a word for word chunk of code you can just directly copy and paste, adapt their code to work for your usecase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) module to get a list of all the weeks in a year, then simply shoose the one you want:

```
import calendar
from itertools import groupby

year = 2020
my_calendar = calendar.Calendar()
weeks = (w for month in range(1, 13) for w in my_calendar.monthdatescalendar(year, month))

# deduplicate the lists
weeks = [k for k, _ in groupby(weeks)]

weeks[1] 
# [datetime.date(2020, 1, 6), datetime.date(2020, 1, 7), datetime.date(2020, 1, 8), datetime.date(2020, 1, 9), datetime.date(2020, 1, 10), datetime.date(2020, 1, 11), datetime.date(2020, 1, 12)]
```

It's then pretty easy to change those date objects to strings in the format you want

```
[d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for d in week[1]]
# ['2020-01-06', '2020-01-07', '2020-01-08', '2020-01-09', '2020-01-10', '2020-01-11', '2020-01-12']
```

Comment: Thats super elegant, thanks!

Comment: A bit weird though, if you do year = 2019 and week = 52, you get November 4 - 10 - thats strange?

Comment: That's a good catch.  If there's a week in two months it's being added to the list twice.  That's easy enough to fix.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost a duplicate to this: [how to get all dates of week based on week number in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56163008/how-to-get-all-dates-of-week-based-on-week-number-in-python/56164212)

To get the week to start from monday you change 0 to 1 on this line

```
startdate = time.asctime(time.strptime('2019 %d 0' % WEEK, '%Y %W %w'))
```

and -2 to -1 here

```
WEEK  = 20 - 2 # as it starts with 0 and you want week to start from sunday
```

Comment: Perhaps this should be a new answer on the duplicate.

Comment: ill do that for future reference